# How to get windows user with flutter web

Tags: windows, flutter

I create a flutter web app and want to read the windows user.
It will only run in our company web and only windows pcs are used.
As of my knownledge dart ffi is not working, because I don't build a windows desktop application.
Are there any other ways?

Thanks a lot!
PatPatWithHat

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for samething please support.

Comment: to make this short: You can't archive this from flutter. At least, this is, what I found out.
I solved it by hosting my flutter app in iis. This allows windows auth to be required. Because I also need data from Active Directory I created a backend service as well with a simple webAPI to retreive the data. Hope this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).